# Amazon Wallet Widget not rendering

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I have been working on this problem for a while now and I can't figure out why the Amazon wallet widget is not rendering. I am implementing a Pay with Amazon only, not Login.  I got the button widget to work, but when it comes time for the wallet to show up, nothing.  I am using BigCommerce as my ecommerce platform.  The button works and takes me to the next page`(https://store-24r5d.mybigcommerce.com/checkout-with-amazon)`but the widget does not render.

Here is my button code (tested and working fine)

```
                                     <!--Amazon Pay Starts Here-->

                    <!-- Place this where you would like the Payment Button to appear
<div id="AmazonPayButton"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var authRequest;
  OffAmazonPayments.Button("AmazonPayButton", "Selleridhere", {
    type:  "PwA",
    color: "Gold",
    size:  "medium",
    useAmazonAddressBook: true,
    authorization: function() {
      var loginOptions = {scope: 'profile payments:widget'};
      authRequest = amazon.Login.authorize(loginOptions, "https://store-24r5d.mybigcommerce.com/checkout-with-amazon/");
    },
    onError: function(error) {
      // Write your custom error handling
    }
  });
</script>

                    <!--Amazon Pay ends Here-->
```

On my custom.css to render the wallet:

```
<!-- please put the style below inside your CSS file -->

#addressBookWidgetDiv{
    width: 400px; 
    height: 228px;
}​
```

On my page where the wallet is supposed to render (here is the issue):

```
     <!--Amazon wallet Widget-->
<div id="addressBookWidgetDiv">
</div> 

<script>
new OffAmazonPayments.Widgets.AddressBook({
  sellerId: 'SellerIDHere,'
  onOrderReferenceCreate: function(orderReference) {
    orderReference.getAmazonOrderReferenceId();
  },
  onAddressSelect: function(orderReference) {
    // Replace the following code with the action that you want to perform 
    // after the address is selected.
    // The amazonOrderReferenceId can be used to retrieve 
    // the address details by calling the GetOrderReferenceDetails
    // operation. If rendering the AddressBook and Wallet widgets on the
    // same page, you should wait for this event before you render the
    // Wallet widget for the first time.
    // The Wallet widget will re-render itself on all subsequent 
    // onAddressSelect events, without any action from you. It is not 
    // recommended that you explicitly refresh it.
  },
  design: {
    designMode: 'responsive'
  },
  onError: function(error) {
    // your error handling code
  }
}).bind("addressBookWidgetDiv");
</script>

<!--Amazon wallet ends here-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are not including the required Amazon widgets js library on the page where your trying to render the addressBook.  To confirm, open up console and see if you get the following error:

> "ReferenceError: OffAmazonPayments is not defined"

If so, simply included the sandbox or production js file:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' 
    src='https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/us/sandbox/js/Widgets.js'>
```

or

```
    <script type='text/javascript' 
    src=='https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/us/js/Widgets.js'>
```

Additionally, your above code is to render Amazon's address book, not wallet.  The wallet (selecting credit card) is required for payment and the address book (selecting shipping address) is optional.  Check https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/lpwa/201749840#201749990 for documentation on adding the wallet (and address book) buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I visited your site and it doesn't appear to be working. FYI, you are using Login with Amazon. When 'Pay with Amazon' is clicked that is the Login with Amazon experience you see asking for your consent.

In addition to adding the widgets code you will also need to set your Login with Amazon client Id in your `<head>` like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onAmazonLoginReady = function () {
        amazon.Login.setClientId('your_login_with_amazon_client_id');
    };
</script>
```

If you don't set the client Id you are likely to see such things as session expiration, etc.

You will need to include this, along with the Widgets.js, on both the "Pay with Amazon" button page and the widgets page.

Widgets.js must be loaded **AFTER** you set the client Id.

Answer (score 0):

The script code given in amazon docs contains the attribute async='async' and looks like this-

```html
<script type='text/javascript' async='async'
  src='https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/us/sandbox/js/Widgets.js'>
</script>
```

Now you have to remove the "async" attribute because it is causing the whole problem. When your code needs `OffAmazonPayments` reference , but the JavaScript file (`.../widgets.js`) is still loading (since it is an asynchronous function).
So just simply remove the "async" attribute, to make that script code like this--

```html
<script type='text/javascript' async='async'
  src='https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/us/sandbox/js/Widgets.js'>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add it to the head tag with async it appears to work that way.

```
<script async type='text/javascript' src='https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/us/sandbox/js/Widgets.js'></script>
```